# Limit of the measure of the converging sequence of sets

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

This is a question from Ash's book, "Probability and Measure Theory".

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$. If $A_n\in\mathcal{F}$, $n=1,2\dots$ and  $A=\lim_nA_n$, show that $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$.

I tried to use $\lim\sup_n A_n=\lim\inf_n A_n=A$, but couldn't manage to get something meaningful. Thanks for any help.

Comment: in what sense is $\lim A_n = A$?

Comment: It is defined when $\lim\sup_n A_n=\cap_{n=1}\cup_{k=n}A_k$ and $\lim\inf_n A_n=\cup_{n=1}\cap_{k=n}A_k$ are equal.

Comment: You haven't made a definition of $sup_nA_n$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show this:

$$\mu (\lim\inf_n A_n) \le \lim\inf_n \mu( A_n) \le  \lim\sup_n \mu( A_n) \le  \mu (\lim\sup_n A_n)$$

the left and right inequalities are similar. The proof will be tedious but should work if you assume that there is a subsequence $A_{n_k}$ such that $\mu(A_{n_k}) > \mu (\lim\sup_n A_n) +\epsilon$ for large enough $k$, .... etc... leading to a contradiction.