# Is a limit of measure of a sequence of sets equal to measure of limit of the sequence of sets?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm sitting at the same question desk as this: [Limit of the measure of the converging sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833097/limit-of-the-measure-of-the-converging-sequence-of-sets).

Actually, I can't prove it neither. PA6OTA gave a hint to show there is subsequence $A_{n_k}$ such that $μ(A_{n_k}) > μ(lim\ sup_n A_n) + ϵ$ for large enough k, leading to a contradiction. I don't know why should I assume a subsequence?

Comment: Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you know Fatou's lemma?

Comment: @saz: I don't know.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I googled it. it seems that Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem is a format of integral?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: you suppose $μ(A_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions?

Comment: @saz: Fatou's lemma is a format of integral as well. But how to turn the integral off so that I can use it to prove my problem?

Comment: Dominated convergence does it, if that's allowed - if dct happens later in the book it would be cheating. To use dct here you have to think a little: Given a measurable set $A$, if you define a function $f$ by _____, then $\int f\,d\mu=\mu(A)$.

Comment: Hint: It's simple...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Characteristic function?

Comment: Right toe${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I've worked out a proof. I didn't use your hint coz its cheating as you mentioned. But I appreciate your enlightenment and I learned something more from dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @saz: I know what is Fatou's lemma and its proof now. And then it reminds me of your comment here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any sequence of sets $(A_n)$ the $\limsup$ is defined by $$\limsup A_n
=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{j=n}^\infty A_j\right)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n.$$ Since the $B_n$ are decreasing, *if* we assume the measure is finite we have $$\mu(\limsup A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n)
=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n).$$But $A_n\subset B_n$, so $\mu(A_n)\le\mu(B_n)$, so the above implies

$$\mu(\limsup A_n)\ge\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n).$$

Similarly (without assuming $\mu$ is finite) for any sets $A_n$ we have 
$$\mu(\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n)\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n).$$

Now suppose $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ exists. By definition this means $$A=\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n.$$ So the two previous inequalities say $$\liminf\mu(A_n)\ge\mu(A)\ge\limsup\mu(A_n).$$Hence $\lim\mu(A_n)$ exists and equals $\mu(A)$.

Comment: Another answer just appeared...

Comment: Thanks David. But it seems $\mu(\limsup A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n)$ has used the conclusion that need to be proved. See, $\mu(\limsup A_n)= \mu (\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n)$, right?

Comment: If $B_n$ is an _increasing_ sequence of sets then the measure of the limit equals the limit of the measures. This is easy; don't know what book you're using but it's in there towards the start. (It's referred to as "continuity from below"). Similarly if $B_n$ is a _decreasing_ sequence of sets, _if_ the measure is finite. (And we must be talking about a finite measure or the result is false. Consider Lebesgue measure on the line, $A_n=[n,\infty)$.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out a proof.

It is not appropriate to write the symbol "$\lim\sup_n A_n$" because $\sup_n A_n$ is not defined. So replace $\lim\sup_n A_n$ by $\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m$ and $\lim\inf_n A_n$ by $\bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m$

Suppose $\lim\sup_n \mu( A_n) > \mu (\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m)$.

Then $\exists$ some rational $r$ with $\lim\sup_n \mu( A_n) > r > \mu (\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m)$(two real numbers $a, b$ satisfy $a > b$ if and only if there is some rational r with $a > r > b$).

So $\exists N ∈ \mathbb N^+$ such that $sup_n \mu (A_n)$ = $sup_n${$μ(A_n), μ(A_{n+1}), ..., μ(A_{\infty})$} $> r > \mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m)$ for all $n \geqslant N$.

Since $sup_n${$μ(A_n), μ(A_{n+1}), ..., μ(A_{\infty})$} $\geqslant$ $sup_{n+1}${$μ(A_{n+1}), μ(A_{n+2}), ..., μ(A_{\infty})$}, then $sup_n \mu (A_n) \geqslant sup_{n+1}  \mu (A_{n+1}) \geqslant .. \geqslant sup_{\infty}  \mu (A_{\infty}) > r > \mu (\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m)$ while actually $sup_{\infty} \mu (A_{\infty}) = \mu (A_{\infty})$. 
Here contradiction $\mu (A_{\infty}) = \mu (A)> r > \mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m)$ where $\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m = A$.

So $\lim\sup_n \mu( A_n) \leqslant \mu (\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m)$.

Similar proof for $\mu (\bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m) \le \lim\inf_n \mu( A_n)$.

Finally, $$\mu (A) = \mu (\bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m) \le \lim\inf_n \mu( A_n) \le  \lim\sup_n \mu( A_n) \le  \mu (\bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{m=k}^{+\infty}A_m) = \mu (A)$$