# Distinction between probability of limit of sequence of events vs. limit of sequence of probabilities of events

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading the answer of Jay.H to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549767/lim-sup-and-lim-infs-of-brownian-motion-b-t-sqrtt-as-t-to-infty-or-as). Some context: Here we are considering a sequence of events $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $A_n:=\sup_{0 \leq s \leq 1/n} B_s/\sqrt{s}<C$. Also, $B_s$ denotes a standard Brownian motion, and $C>0$ is arbitrary.

The part of his proof where I have some doubts is when he states that, if we let $A:=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n$:

$$P(A) = P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)$$

Why can we do this interchange? I have read this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833097/limit-of-the-measure-of-the-converging-sequence-of-sets) for instance, and it seems that we used it in our case. As I undestand $P$ is a finite measure (of course) since it lies between $0$ and $1$, and all of the events $A_n$ lie in $\mathcal{F}_1$ for instance. Is this justification correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sup_{0 \leq s \leq 1/n} B_s/\sqrt{s}<C$ implies that $\sup_{0 \leq s \leq 1/{n+1}} B_s/\sqrt{s}<C$ . In other words, $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$. This implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n)=  P(\bigcup_n A_n)=P(\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't get it. In your first equality you seem to have moved inside the limit, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = \cup_n A_n$. Could you maybe give conditions under which we can interchange it? And if so, why?

Comment: In any measure space $A_n$ increasing to $A$ implies $\mu (A_n) \to \mu (A)$. And $\lim A_n$ is nothing but $\bigcup A_n$ in this case. So $\mu (\lim A_n)=\mu (A)=\lim \mu(A_n)$. @Sarah